# Change MariaDB 10.5.5 Port

Tags: mysql, mariadb, port, mariadb-10.5

I have installed MariaDB **10.5.5** in Ubuntu 20.04 server. Right now I try to change the default port of the database to let say **12345**. When I look into `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` and `/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.conf` there is no **port** options, then I add `port = 5505` inside `/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.conf` under `[mysqld]`, then I restart the mariadb-server using `sudo systemctl restart mysql` & `sudo systemctl restart mariadb`. But when I connect the mariadb server using `mysql -uusername -p`, it's just connected. The expected behavior is mysql client will reject the connection. I also try to use `mysql -uusername -p -P123222`, but still connected. My questions is how can I can change the port and prevent this strange behavior to happen?

Comment: mariadb connects via a unix socket by default. Its a bit odd that a port is ignored until a host is specified. Its been that way for a long time.

Comment: Hello @danblack, thank you for replying. I see, noted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you don't specify a hostname, the default hostname "localhost" will be assumed, so the connection will be established via unix_socket and not via TCP/IP.

To connect via port use e.g.

```
mysql -h127.0.0.1 -P12345 -uusername -p
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for replying. I try that command and it works as expected, :D

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 places, at least, where you may find the

```
port = 3306
```

Make sure you are changing them all, but specifically the one under the section `[mysqld]`

```
[mysqld]
port = 3307
```

It is this one that tells the deamon which port to use.

My guess is you changed the one under `[client]`

So change both :)

Comment: Hi! Thank you for replying, I check it again and ready make sure, it's on the right configuration file /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.conf and under section [mysqld], it's actually me not stating the host when connecting with the mariadb server. The solution provided by @georg work perfectly.

Comment: or use `[client-server]`  and configure the port for both one hit. If you look at `mysqld --help --verbose` it shows which sections are read.